# Prevent 3rd party libraries to get my push notifications

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

My app is implementing FCM as so as a 3rd party library I use. My Problem is every time I send a notification through the console the 3rd Party has a broadcast receiver registered like this

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".ThirdPartyReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

that is able to get the content of all my notifications, how I can prevent this? atm I'm initializing and using an instance of firebase app using my credentials like this:

```
FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setApplicationId(id)
        .setApiKey(api)
        .setDatabaseUrl(databaseurl)
        .setGcmSenderId(senderId)
        .setProjectId(projectId)
        .build()
```

But looks like FCM only rely on the packageName to deliver push notifications and any third-party library contained in my project can register to get the push notifications, is there a way to prevent this?

Observation, manually disabling all unknown receivers prevents this, but then the library doesn't get the notifications anymore and I break its functionality.

Comment: "that is able to get the content of all my notifications, how I can prevent this?"  seems to conflict with "then the library doesn't get the notifications anymore and I break its functionality". Either get rid of the library, or use the library (and live with the fact that the library needs access to your notifications to help you with those notifications).

Comment: @CommonsWare The library is a core part of the app. They have their FCM project, management and everything else and their notifications only matter to them, something like Intercom or Zendesk integration. My App has my own FCM project, and I need my notifications. What I'm trying to prevent is their receiver to receive my notifications. I don't want to force/disable it programmatically because it will break the third-party functionality. I thought FCM FirebaseApp should be tied to the GCM sender somehow and only deliver/notify the proper receiver.

Comment: Do you have your own defined class extending `FirebaseMessagingService` by chance? Just seeing if that would intercept them coming inbound.

Comment: Hi @Silmarilos, I do have my own defined class extending `FirebaseMessagingService` and extending this one seems to work just about right, but the receiver for `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE` registered by the library is still able to get my notification content, even if register another receiver on top of it. I still have to try János solution about the broadcast priority

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure FCM uses ordered broadcast or not, but if it does then you have to :

1. change the priority of your `BroadcastReveiver` (for example in `AndroidManifest.xml`) and
2. call `abortBroadcast()` in `onReceive()` implementation to prevent any other broadcast receivers from receiving the broadcast.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#abortBroadcast()

It may help you.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it (not tested)

1. Remove other receivers from the app manifest. I think this can be done with `tools:node="remove"` strategy of [manifest merger](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge#node_markers)

   ```
   <receiver tools:node="remove"
       android:name=".ThirdPartyReceiver"
       android:exported="true"
       android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" />
   ```
2. Make your own implementation of `FirebaseMessagingService` follow a proxy pattern, i.e. invoke `ThirdPartyReceiver` if that's not a message you can handle.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is giving highest priority (Max 1000) to your receiver and use  `abortBroadcast();` to stop it from forwarding to next receiver but you need correct permission added in your AndroidManifest.xml

Above code will be absolute soon don't use broadcast receiver. Read bellow link.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

Now you have to migrate to new mechanism. Follow this link for migration.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm